# --Problem with virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

I work on UBUNTU. And I have windows on my virtualbox. Yesterday when I updated my Ubuntu I am not able to start my virtualbox. It is giving me following error message.Please if anyone can help me.

```
The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
available for the current kernel (3.2.0-72-generic) or it failed to
load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

After that I run the following command:

```
archana@archana-Vostro-1450:~$ sudo apt-get install dkms
[sudo] password for archana: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libpam-winbind ttf-umefont wine1.4-amd64 gcompris-data wine1.4 ttf-dustin
language-pack-kde-zh-hans-base libcapi20-3 firefox-locale-zh-hans unixodbc
wine1.4-common wine-gecko1.4 wine-gecko1.4:i386 winetricks libgif4:i386
language-pack-kde-en wine kde-l10n-engb wine1.4-i386:i386 fonts-dustin
language-pack-zh-hans-base ttf-unfonts-core libmpg123-0 kde-l10n-zhcn
language-pack-zh-hans language-pack-kde-zh-hans winbind libodbc1 fonts-droid
language-pack-kde-en-base python-pysqlite2 gcompris-sound-en ttf-droid
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
fakeroot
The following NEW packages will be installed:
dkms fakeroot
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 160 kB of archives.
After this operation, 669 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
dkms fakeroot
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Get:1 http://repo.iitd.ernet.in/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main dkms all 2.2.0.3-1ubuntu3.2 [72.6 kB]
Get:2 http://repo.iitd.ernet.in/ubuntu/ precise/main fakeroot amd64 1.18.2-1 [87.2 kB]
Fetched 160 kB in 1s (115 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 322489 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking dkms (from .../dkms_2.2.0.3-1ubuntu3.2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Unpacking fakeroot (from .../fakeroot_1.18.2-1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.18.2-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode.
archana@archana-Vostro-1450:~$ sudo virtualbox
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
available for the current kernel (3.2.0-72-generic) or it failed to
load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
^Carchana@archana-Vostro-1450:~$ ^C
archana@archana-Vostro-1450:~$ run sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
No command 'run' found, did you mean:
 Command 'zrun' from package 'moreutils' (universe)
 Command 'runq' from package 'exim4-daemon-heavy' (main)
 Command 'runq' from package 'sendmail-bin' (universe)
 Command 'runq' from package 'exim4-daemon-light' (main)
 Command 'grun' from package 'grun' (universe)
 Command 'qrun' from package 'torque-client' (universe)
 Command 'qrun' from package 'torque-client-x11' (universe)
 Command 'lrun' from package 'lustre-utils' (universe)
 Command 'rn' from package 'trn' (multiverse)
 Command 'rn' from package 'trn4' (multiverse)
 Command 'rup' from package 'rstat-client' (universe)
 Command 'srun' from package 'slurm-llnl' (universe)
run: command not found
archana@archana-Vostro-1450:~$
```

Comment: how did you install virtalbox ? Did you run `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` ? If that command works, you have to update the vbox kernel module with each kernel update. It is usually easier to install the vbox package in the ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Ye I have tried it and got the result:archana@archana-Vostro-1450:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv
[sudo] password for archana: 
Usage: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv {start|stop|stop_vms|restart|force-reload|status|setup}                                                          what should I do next?
archana@archana-Vostro-1450:~$

Comment: You forgot the "setup" at the end and thus are getting a usage error. `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` . The alternate, once again, is to intstall virtualbox from the repositories. Better, use KVM. Virtmanager is a ggraphical front end for KVM and KVM is open source and part of the kernel (so no 3rd party apps).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling Virtualbox and importing the Virtualmachine by running the .vdi (or whatever Disk image format you are using)?

Comment: No i have not tried this. I am afraid if reinstalling would affect windows and files stored on it. I have lots of data stored there.

Comment: A backup is the first thing you should do. then try to get the virtualbox deinstalled without deleting the image of your windows. create a new windows machine with the existing windows image and try to start it.